# Java WorldWind Surface Shape causing Rendering Artifacts

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, worldwind

I'm using NASA WorldWind for Java to display some surface shapes, and I am seeing some strange artifacting occurring.  I am running this example to show what is happening:  https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/blob/develop/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/SurfaceShapes.java.  Its strange because it only seems to affect Surface Shapes and it is only happening on this hardware (This seems to run as expected on Windows).  Here is my hardware information:

```
Red Hat Linux Workstation 6.10 (Santiago)

2.6.32-754.17.1.el6.x86_64

lscpi | grep ‘VGA’

VGA Compatible Controller:  Matrox Electronics Systems LTd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a) 

glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

In this screenshot, I am zoomed out:

[image]

Now I zoom in, and the shapes are there, and they themselves look correct:

[image]

Now if I turn off the Surface Shapes layer, the globe itself renders correctly:

[image]

I have limited ability to upgrade the hardware or install drivers, so I'm hoping there is some JOGL/OpenGL primitive I can apply to fix the issue.

I'm thinking the problem is likely in:

https://github.com/nasa/World-Wind-Java/blob/master/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/AbstractSurfaceObject.java

or

https://github.com/nasa/World-Wind-Java/blob/master/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/SurfaceObjectTileBuilder.java

Has anyone seen this before or have any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use VMWare for your tests and let us know whether the problem persist.

Comment: I've replicated it on various flavors on RHEL now; most of them over VNC or XRDP.  Its unclear to me at the moment if that is part of the problem or just a coincidence

Comment: Some more investigation is leading me to believe it has to do with the 'useMipmaps' flag in SurfaceObjectTileBuilder

Comment: Don't use any remote desktop solutions first to determine whether it's part of the problem.

Comment: If anyone can answer the implications of turning off useMipmaps, they can get the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own with some luck.  In [SurfaceObjectTileBuilder.java](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/blob/41cf5c6f77d9953adda18773884fb5b8ac5a7df9/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/SurfaceObjectTileBuilder.java) setting useMipmaps to false seems to fix the issue:

```
/** Controls if mip-maps are generated for surface tile textures. */
protected boolean useMipmaps = true;
```

Its not obvious what the negative side effects are or if this has performance implications, but for the time being it gets rid of the artifacting.